# .net api tracing with opentelemetry

Tags: .net, open-telemetry

I am sure someone has already had this problem but unfortunately not posted anywhere...
I have a simple .net webapi and using opentelemetry for tracing (`https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/examples/AspNetCore/Program.cs`)
The full registration looks as follows:

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.AddService(
        serviceName: "my-web-api",
        serviceVersion: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()?.InformationalVersion,
        serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName))
          .WithTracing(y =>
           {
                y.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();

                y.AddOtlpExporter(x =>
                {
                    x.Endpoint = new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("OtlpExporter:Endpoint"));
                });
           });
```

After I set it up - everything works just fine and I can see traces appearing in `Tempo`
But - as soon the api gets called by another api - no traces gets recorded (as if the request did not happen). The root cause of this is that the calling api is adding a header called `traceparent` with a random guid like value. Such incoming requests are just being skipped for some reason.
I am using the latest library versions as of now:

```
OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console 1.5.1
OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol 1.5.1
OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting 1.5.1"
OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore 1.5.0-beta.1
```

Again - this seems like something pretty trivial, but not that obvious to locate the real cause of this.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try adding .SetSampler<AlwaysOnSampler>() in both APIs and see if it fixes ir. If it doesn't (or someone else) can add an answer)

Comment: Does the *other* API use OTEL? Is the *collector* configured to use sampling? If the collector decides to *not* collect the parent trace, your own service's trace won't be collected either. Try adding another exporter, eg to Jaeger or the console, to see your own application's traces.

Answer (score 3):

[By default](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/docs/trace/customizing-the-sdk/README.md#samplers), the OpenTelemetry .NET SDK uses the sampling configuration `ParentBased(root=AlwaysOn)`. Which means, if a trace is to be continued (via a `traceparent` header on an incoming request), the sampling decision encoded in the `traceparent` header is used. If a new trace is started, it will be always sampled. In your case, this encoded sampling decision is most likely set to not sample most of the time.

In your case, if you want to see all traces of the downstream service, independent of the upstream samplign decision, add this configuration:

```
.SetSampler<AlwaysOnSampler>()
```

If you want to see a certain percentage of traces of the downstream service, independent of the upstream samplign decision, add this configuration:

```
.SetSampler(new TraceIdRatioBasedSampler(0.25))
```

For most production cases, you probably want to use a `ParentBasedSampler` combined with a `TraceIdRatioBasedSampler`.